# Limiting number of failed UAC password attempts?

Tags: windows, passwords, uac

Is there any way to limit or throttle the number of attempts at entering a password in the UAC prompt?

Putting limits on how many times a password can be entered (either absolute or per time interval) is pretty standard practice, and Windows provides such a function at the login screen, so I would find it odd if it did not also allow this for the UAC prompt as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing this

## 1. Via the Local Group Policy Editor

###### Press the (`Windows Key` + `R`), type `gpedit.msc` and hit `Enter`, or open the Start Menu (`Windows Key`) and type `gpedit.msc` and hit `Enter`.

Both of these methods should work to open the Group Policy editor. If it does not work, then you are most likely not using a Professional Edition of Windows (Windows 10/11 Pro etc.) If you're running on a home edition, try using [Policy Plus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) and follow the instructions

###### Navigate to `Computer Configuration` > `Windows Settings` > `Security Settings` > `Account Policies` > `Account Lockout Policy`.

Click the corresponding key. You should see the following four settings in the right-hand side pane:

- `Account lockout duration`
- `Account lockout threshold`
- `Allow Administration account lockout`
- `Reset account lockout counter after`

[image: screenshot for reference]

You will need both the `Account lockout threshold` policy for determining how many invalid logon attempts are required until Windows locks the account and `Account lockout duration` to determine how long the account stays locked. **Double-click the `Account lockout threshold` policy, which should show you the following screen. Using the box given, enter your desired value and click `Ok`.** If set to `0`, then Windows will not lock the account regardless of how many attempts were made.

[image]

The `Reset account lockout counter after` policy determines how long (in minutes) before Windows "forgets" about the incorrect attempts made and resets the counter to `0`. **Double-click the policy and use the box to enter your desired value, then click `Ok`.** To make this easier to understand, you can set the `Account lockout threshold` to 5 and the `Reset account lockout counter after` policy to 5. This will give the user **5 attempts within 5 minutes** before being locked out. This policy cannot be edited unless `Account lockout threshold` has been set to anything other than 0.

[image]

The `Account lockout duration` policy is nearly self-explainable. Its value (in minutes) determines how long Windows stays locked until it is unlocked automatically. This setting also requires `Account lockout threshold` to be set beforehand. For example, you can set the `Account lockout threshold` to 5 and the `Account lockout duration` to 5. If **all five attempts are used, your account will lock for five minutes** before automatically unlocking. As with previous policies, **Double-click the policy, and enter your desired value, then click `Ok`.**

[image]

When finished, close the Policy Editor and reboot Windows to apply.

## 2. Via Command Prompt (Administrator)

- To open Command Prompt as Administrator, **press `Windows Key` + `R` and type `cmd`, then press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.

For any/each command, replace `5` with your desired value to determine the amount of attempts made before locking the account. **Replace with `0` to reset to default, which disables the policy**.

To configure the Account lockout threshold, type the following command:

```
net accounts /lockoutthreshold:5
```

For `Reset account lockout counter after`:

```
net accounts /lockoutwindow:5
```

And `Account lockout duration`:

```
net accounts /lockoutduration:5
```

When finished, reboot the PC to apply changes.

Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/how-limit-number-failed-login-attempts-windows-10/

Comment: Then you should quote it here (and leave the link intact).  Because the link may disappear one day.

Comment: @RohitGupta could you remove your downvote please now that I've added the information?

Comment: The downvote was not mine.  But I have upvoted it now.